# In an AppSync GraphQL transform, can I set an @auth rule AuthStrategy based on a field in the table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Is there a way to conditionally set more than one AuthStrategy depending on a field in the table?

Let's say I have a blog Post type:

```
type Post
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [read, update, delete] },
  ])
{
  id: ID!
  owner: String!
  visibility: Visibility!
  title: String!
  body: String!
  whitelist: [String!]  
}

enum Visibility {
  PUBLIC,
  PRIVATE,
  PROTECTED,
  SECRET
}
```

I want the creator to be able to set whether the Post is:

1. Public: anyone can see it, logged in or not.
2. Private: any logged-in user can see it.
3. Protected: this array of users can see it.
4. Secret: only the creator can see it.

I know how to hardcode each of these. But programmatically...

Is this even possible, or are AppSync transforms just too basic, and I need to use a custom resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, this does require a custom resolver—or custom, nested resolver—which is pretty easy.

The official docs on this authorization scenario: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authorization-use-cases.html.

And a great Hacker Noon article on this authorization scenario: https://hackernoon.com/graphql-authorization-with-multiple-data-sources-using-aws-appsync-dfae2e350bf2.